# Sublime text 3: команда переключить язык на английский

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Требуется переключить язык на английский.
Сделать это нужно не нажатием Alt+Shift, а внутренней командой SublimeText3.
Какой командой это можно сделать?

Подробнее: Есть плагин EasyMotion. При нажатии на ctrl+; и затем любую клавишу (букву в тексте, куда нужно перейти), EasyMotion подсвечивает эту букву на всей странице (эта буква может быть повсюду). Подсвечивает следующим образом: он заменяет ее на букву английского алфавита. Чтобы переместить курсор к этой букве, нужно нажать соответствующую букву английского алфавита. Так вот в любом случае, после нажатия на ctrl+;+буква нужно переключаться на английскую раскладку. Это рутиное действие. А так как стоит задача перемещаться по тексту без помощи мыши - это весьма частое рутиное действие. Каждый раз переключаться с языка на язык не очень удобно. Было бы здорово, чтобы Sublime Text, после нажатия на ctrl+;+буква, автоматически переводил раскладку в английский язык. А идеально - переводил бы еще и на прежний язык, после нажатия на букву английского алфавита.

Переключение языка на английский могу сделать с помощью AutoHotkey, но тогда потребуется запустить этот .ahk файл из под Sublime Text. Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Зависит от ОС. Саблайм о раскладках клавиатуры пользователя ничего не знает, не говоря уже о переключении.

Comment: я думаю, что Sublime Text не такой могучий, как вы думаете)))

Comment: Юрий Жулин, **1)** если как можно подробнее расскажете, что Вы имели в виду под `Требуется переключить язык на английский.`, будет неплохо. Приведите пример желаемого поведения. Чем больше расскажете, тем больше вероятность, что Вам помогут или подскажут обходной путь. **2)** а) У меня нет английской раскладки на компьютере, б) Пользуюсь раскладками [**Colemak**](https://colemak.com/), в) У меня 3 раскладки, а не 2, г) [**Переключаю раскладки посредством `CapsLock`, а не `Alt+Shift`**](https://superuser.com/q/1169680/572069). Таких пользователей Вам придётся учитывать.

Comment: **3)** для взаимодействия с Windows API есть модуль [**Pywin32**](https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32), вероятно, через Sublime Text можно взаимодействовать и с macOS или *nix-подобными ОС. Правда, не думаю, что это просто. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за интерес Александр! Как можно более подробнее описал свой замысел.